# Can a React.js parent component request data from child component?

Tags: reactjs

You can easily pass data from a child component to a parent component using callbacks. But these callbacks must be child-driven. In other words, the child component decides when to pass the data to the parent.

Is there a way where my parent component can arbitrarily access a child's `state` data without needing the child to initiate any data passing? Is there a way to do this without refactoring the child's `state`, moving it up one level?

Answer (score 1):

By your description I'd say there is no way to access child's state by parent. You could store the state IN parent and control it by child if you need it often, or you could use something like Redux for that, but it also will be a global state, not only child's one.

P.S. If you want better detailed answer, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options,

1: Using Callbacks
,2: Using Redux 
,3: Using React’s Context API

(Options 2 and 3 also can use for siblings, children to parents requests)

An example of callback

1 Parent Component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  state = { msg: "" }

  callBackFunc = (childData) => {
        this.setState({msg: childData})
   },

  render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <Child1 parentCallback = 
                   {this.callBackFunc}/>
                <p> {this.state.msg} </p>

              </div>
            );
    }
}
```

2 Child Component

```
class Child1 extends React.Component{

sendData = () => {
         this.props.parentCallback("a message for pass to parent");
    },

render() { 
    //call function sendData
    }

};
```